# Android: how to force GridView width to wrap_content?

Tags: android

My GridView contains columns of fixed width, with fixed horizontal spacing.  If there are not enough columns to fill the screen horziontally, I would like my GridView's width to wrap to its contents, and to center vertical in the screen.

However, regardless of the number of columns I use, the GridView's width grows to fill the screen.  The attached image shows this, where the green GridView fills the screen horizontally, despite having only 3 columns and its width being set to "wrap_content".

```
public class Temp extends Activity
{
    private GridView grid;
    private int columnWidth = 80;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridview, null);
        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
        grid.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());

        setContentView(view);
    }

    class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        public GridAdapter() 
        {
        }

        public int getCount() 
        {
            return 3;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            View ret;

            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                ret = new ImageView(Temp.this);
                ret.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(columnWidth, 100));
                ret.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else
            {   
                ret= convertView;
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dip"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center">
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing `android:numColumns="auto_fit"`.

Comment: I changed android:numColumns=3; no difference

Comment: Have you tried altering `stretchMode` to `none`?

Comment: Just tried with "none". Result: http://i.imgur.com/cmLzD.png

Comment: The one thing I have found that works is if I set gridview's layoutparam's width = numcolums*(columnWidth + horizontalSpacing) + leftMargin + rightMargin.  But this seems like what wrap_content should be doing....

Comment: I suggest having a look at the source code for `GridView` to see how it operates.  Also google `FlowLayout`.  Reto Meier gave an example of a custom `ViewGroup`

Comment: Ok, looking at the source for GridView.onMeasure(), width is set to the parent's width, regardless of if its MeasureSpec is AT_MOST or EXACTLY (wrap_content, or match_parent).   So, fiddling with GridView's layoutparams and attributes will do no good.  I guess my above idea about calculating the width is reasonable?

Comment: I presume you are doing that in code?  Since you need to know the screen width of the device.  Does it not also leave the `GridView` at the whole screen width? And just move the containing views?  Have a look at the `FlowLayout`, I am pretty sure it does what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` is extremely annoying with this kind of stuff to say the least. In your case, the issue is that saying `auto_fit` is essentially telling GridView to always fit it horizontally unfortunately. What you could try is to center the individual `ImageView`s in the row. But then this requires you to change how you have it set up. Rather than have the columns auto fit, just have 1 item per row, but inflate a LinearLayout that has the orientation as horizontal. Then center the Linear Layout with the ImageViews also in it in each row. Hopefully that provides some ideas.

Comment: While this would work, manually placing my image views into columns within a linearlayout seems like it would kill the point of a GridView. ..

Comment: Who said anything about manually? You can inflate the LinearLayout from a seperate file, or even dynamically create it in code, and you can continue with what you have above. The main difference is that you need to inflate some extra stuff, but besides that, it would work. auto_fit essentially fits it according to the size of the ImageView you are using. Each row would have the same number assuming there was more than 1 row. This means you can pick a max number of Views to fit into the LinearLayout. Its a little extra work, but its very doable.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add two empty views at left and right of GridView with weight = 1 and assign 0.5 weight to GridView. Eg.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/myGridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout suggested above did not work for me.

In the end I found it easiest to achieve the results you want by programatically setting the width and X location of the grid -- using the setX(float) method to center the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an old question, but this is the answer:

```
public class GridViewEx extends GridView {

//private int mRequestedNumColumns = 0;

public GridViewEx(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public GridViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public GridViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}



@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int numcol=getNumColumns();
    int numitems=getAdapter().getCount();

    if(numitems<numcol){
        int width = (numitems * getColumnWidth())
                + ((numitems -1) * getHorizontalSpacing())
                + getListPaddingLeft() + getListPaddingRight();

        setMeasuredDimension(width, getMeasuredHeight());
    }

}
```

}

And when you add or delete elements from your adapter you have to call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
gridView.invalidate()
```

Comment: thanks, I was very frustrated about this 6 years ago